# Boundary layer in time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, perturbation-theory, boundary-layer

Consider the initial value problem $\varepsilon x'' + x' + tx = 0$ where $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 1$. I'm solving this problem using a matched asymptotic expansion. First, I let $$x(t, \varepsilon) = \varepsilon x_1(t) + \varepsilon^2 x_2(t) + o(\varepsilon^2),$$ and solve at corresponding orders of $\varepsilon$ and leave the coefficients undetermined. Then I define $T = t/\varepsilon$ and let $X(\varepsilon, T) = x(\varepsilon, t)$ and write the re-scaled equation $$X'' + X' + \varepsilon TX = 0.$$

Then solve this at the corresponding orders of $\varepsilon$ for the expansion $$X(\varepsilon, T) = \varepsilon X_1(T) + \varepsilon^2 X_2(T) + o(\varepsilon^3).$$ Assuming $X$ is my solution 'inside' the boundary layer, I let $X$ satisfy the initial conditions $X(0) = 0, X'(0) = \varepsilon$. Then $X_1(0) = 0, X_1'(0) = 1$ and $X_n(0) = 0, X_n'(0) = 0$ where $n>1$. However, when I solve for the solutions 'inside' the boundary layer I get imaginary error functions. I believe this will cause me problems later in the matching.

I believe I have solved this problem without the $t$ term and I am building up to a more complicated function. I am familiar with boundary laters in the context of space, but cannot find much on these 'initial layer' problems.

I know I have not provided my solutions here, but I want to know if my method is sensible or if someone knows a better method of solving this (equations of this type). I appreciate your response.

Comment: There is a lot happening in this problem, especially at $t=0$. I think WKB theory is the way forward, but the $tx$ term leads to strange behaviour and requires careful treatment. There is an exact solution in terms of Airy functions, for what its worth.

Comment: Thank you, I will try WKB. I didn't think about the exact solution, but to find that I'm assuming you transform the equation by an exponential to get Airy's equation? Also I hope you don't mind me asking here, the idea is to next solve a similar equation but with $\cos(\omega t)$x instead, I'm assuming either WKB or multiple time scales for this? I understand that Floquet theory applies as it is a periodic/constant ode, but I don't think that it will be useful to obtain the asymptotic solution.

Comment: After fiddling around with it, I'm actually unsure how to solve the equation exactly either

Comment: Yes, you can use a transformation $x(t)=exp^{-t/\epsilon}W(t)$ to reduce the equation to $\epsilon W''+tW=0$, which has solutions in Airy and Bairy functions (Airy functions of first and second kind). I'm pretty sure this works.

Comment: With equations like $\epsilon x''(t)+x'(t)+r(t)x(t)=0$, you run into issues when $r(t)=0$. Depending on whether $\cos(\omega t)$ is greater or less than zero the solution will either oscillate or be exponential, and when it's zero there will be "connection regions" to match these. I wonder whether averaging could be helpful here, but I'm not familiar with that technique unfortunately. I really hope someone can provide an answer to this question.

Comment: For the problem with $\cos(t)$, it seems like straight WKB can provide a good approximation:
$$ \frac{\epsilon e^{(1-\epsilon)\sin(t)-\epsilon\left(t+\sin(t)\cos(t)\right)/2}\left(e^{-2(1-\epsilon)\sin(t)}-e^{-t/\epsilon}\right)}{1-2\epsilon+2\epsilon^2} $$
This seems to be valid for all time, $O(\epsilon^2)$ accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the update @David. I believe I have got a reasonable approximation using WKB for the case of $\cos(t)$. At a glance, it looks similar to yours - they're most likely equivalent, I just have not factorised it. The answer I accepted mentioned you had deleted an answer giving an overview of the problem with multiple scales, will you be reposting? If not that is fine - I am just unfamiliar with multiple time scales, so would be nice to see.

Comment: I undeleted the multiple scales answer. There are probably a bunch of ways to write the WKB result and have it still $O(\epsilon^2)$ accurate even if it's not just a rearrangement. I'm not sure sure why it works for all time with all the turning points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### WKB approximation

Look for basis solutions of the form $x(t)=\exp(S(t)/ε)$. Then $εx'(t)=S'(t)\exp(S(t)/ε)$ and $ε^2x''(t)=[εS''(t)+S'(t)^2]\exp(S(t)/ε)$. Inserting and canceling the exponential gives
$$
0=e^{-S/ε}(ε^2x''+εx'+εtx)=εS''(t)+S'(t)^2+S'(t)+εt
\\~~\\
\iff S'(t)^2+S'(t)=-ε(S''(t)+t).
$$
For simplicity name $s(t)=S'(t)$ and compute the terms of the perturbation series $s(t)=s_0(t)+εs_1(t)+...$
\begin{array}{rlrl|rl}
s_0^2+s_0&=0                     &\implies s_0&=0      &\text{ or }~~ s_0&=-1\\
2s_0s_1+s_1&=-t                  &\implies s_1&=-t     & s_1&=t \\
s_1^2+2s_0s_2+s_2&=-s_1'         &\implies s_2&=1-t^2  & s_2&=1+t^2\\
\end{array}

The approximation so far is
$$
x(t)=A\exp(-\tfrac12t^2+ε(t-\tfrac13t^3))+B\exp(-ε^{-1}t+\tfrac12t^2+ε(t+\tfrac13t^3))
$$
with $0=x(0)=A+B$ and $1=x'(0)=-ε^{-1}B$, so that $A=ε$, $B=-ε$.

The plot of these two approximations against the numerical solution gives a good fit even for largish values of $ε$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @LutzL, this was definitely very useful - I can only click one of your answers to be my 'answer', so I will respond here. I just have a few questions: i) I'm unsure where you get the Taylor series from in the Perturbation Methods answer (I'm certain I'm just missing something straight froward). ii) I'm not very familiar with two-timing methods, but is there any reason you chose that form for the 'slowly moving' solutions, or is there other forms? iii) The leading order term, B_0 grows exponentially in time (squared), I'm unsure how this doesn't give divergence.

Comment: cont. My guess for iii) is that exp{-t/e} approaches zero quicker than exp{t^2}? But this isn't clear to me. Thank you once again.

Comment: That's ok, I only separated the two because editing a long answer in the browser is uncomfortable. And as these approaches are sufficiently distinct, I deemed it justified.

Comment: ii) The general two-scale approach is explored in the still deleted answer of David (from Sep 25), I expect he will fix what he sees wrong with it and undeletes it. i) If you mean the first sentences, just insert the initial conditions into the ODE to compute the second derivative. iii) Yes, that diverges, or rather grows away from zero, for $t\gg ε^{-1}$. These approximations are only valid for bounded intervals where the bound does not depend on $ε$.

Comment: @Lutzl I couldn't resolve the issues with my answer, I couldn't manage to avoid the secular terms.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a scale error in your re-balanced equation that might throw off later computations.

### Perturbation series

Note: As $x''(0)=-ε^{-1}$, etc., the first terms of the Taylor expansion are $x-\frac12ε^{-1}x^2+O(x( ε^{-1}x)^2)$ which has a peak at $x=ε$ of magnitude $ε/2$. This means that simultaneously to rescaling the time, it makes sense to also scale to compensate the function so that the initial slope remains $1$.

With $X(T)=ε^{-1}x(εT)$ and thus $X'(T)=x'(εT)$, $X''(T)=εx''(εT)$ you should get
$$
X''(T)+X'(T)=εx''(εT)+x'(εT)=-εTx(εT)
\\
\implies X''(T)+X'(T)+ε^2TX(T)=0, ~~X(0)=0,~~X'(0)=1.
$$
which means that the perturbation parameter is $ε^2$, $X(T)=X_0(T)+ε^2X_1(T)+ε^4X_2(T)+...$.
The first order approximation is $X_0(T)=1-e^{-T}$.  The next term is obtained via
\begin{align}
X_1''(T)+X_1'(T)&=-TX_0(T)=-T+Te^{-T}, ~~X_1(0)=0,~~X_1'(0)=0\\
X_1(T)&=-\tfrac12T^2-(\tfrac12T^2+T+1)e^{-T}
\end{align}
Further terms will have higher polynomial degrees, leading to divergence for $T\to \infty$ and thus no match to the outer solution.

However, knowing that the outer solution is $Ce^{-t^2/2}=Ce^{-ε^2T^2/2}=C(1-\frac12ε^2T^2+...)$, one can absorb the obvious terms of the perturbation expansion in similar terms
\begin{align}
X(T)=X_0(T)+ε^2X_1(T)+...&=1-\tfrac12T^2-(1+ε^2(\tfrac12T^2+T+1))e^{-T}+...\\
&=e^{-ε^2T^2/2}-e^{ε^2T^2/2}e^{-T} - ε^2(T+1)e^{-T}
\end{align}
or
$$
x(t)=εe^{-t^2/2}-εe^{t^2/2}e^{-t/ε}-ε^2(t+ε)e^{-t/ε}
$$
(or possibly also $x(t)=εe^{-t^2/2}-ε(2-e^{-t^2/2})e^{-t/ε}+...$, depending on the higher order terms)

But this is guess-work that could be invalidated with every new term in the perturbation series.

---

### Two time-scale approach

Coming from a slightly different angle, starting from the inner solution, set the integration constants there directly as "slowly moving" functions of $t$, that is, try to find a two-scale solution as $$x(t)=εA(t)-εB(t)e^{-t/ε}.$$ Then immediately $A(0)=B(0)$. With the derivatives one finds the other initial condition and the insertion into the differential equation.
\begin{align}
x'(t)&=εA'(t)+(B(t)-εB'(t))e^{-t/ε}, \\
εx''(t)&=ε^2A''(t)-(B(t)-2εB'(t)+ε^2B''(t))e^{-t/ε}, \\ \hline
0=εx''(t)x'(t)+tx(t)&=ε[εA''(t)+A'(t)+tA(t)] - ε[-B'(t)+εB''(t)+tB(t)] e^{-t/ε},\\
1&=ε(A'(0)-B'(0))+B(0).
\end{align}
In first order, separating the terms in $A$ and $B$ and using only the lowest order terms in $ε$, one finds the coefficients as $A_0(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$ and $B_0(t)=e^{t^2/2}$.

In the next order of $A(t)=A_0(t)+εA_1(t)$, $B(t)=B_0(t)+εB_1(t)$,
$$
(e^{t^2/2}A_1(t))'=-(t^2-1)\implies A_1(t)=(t-\frac13t^3)e^{-t^2/2}\\
(e^{-t^2/2}B_1(t))'=(t^2+1)\implies B_1(t)=(t+\frac13t^3)e^{t^2/2}
$$
so that $A'(0)=-ε$, $B'(0)=ε$, and again $A(0)=B(0)=1$

Plotting plots of these first and second order approximations against the numerical solution gives a good fit.

[image]

Comment: But doesn't $x(t)=\epsilon e^{-t^2/2}-\epsilon e^{t^2/2}e^{-t/\epsilon}$ eventually blowup and invalidate the expansion? It's certainly good for early-time.

Comment: @David : Yes, these scale relations remain only valid if $t$ (or $r(t)$) is bounded, and that independent of $ε$. If $t\sim ε^{-1}$ and even more for $t\sim ε^{-2}$, the assignment of the last term $tx(t)$ to the perturbation scales changes and thus the approximate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using matched asymptotic expansions will lead to secular terms at $O(\epsilon^2)$. The $O(\epsilon)$ inner solution is $X_1(T)=1-e^{-T}$ and the outer solution is $x_1(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$. These give a uniform approximation $$x(t)=\epsilon\left(e^{-t^2/2}-e^{-t/\epsilon}\right)+O(\epsilon^2).$$
This approximation is actually quite good. Unfortunately however, the $O(\epsilon^2)$ terms contain secular terms and grow without bound.

To resolve this, use the method of multiple scales. Let $t_1=t$ and $t_2=\epsilon t$, then $x(t)=X(t_1,t_2)$. The equation for $X$ becomes (using subscripts to denote differentiation)
$$ \epsilon X_{t_1t_1}+2X_{t_1t_2}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}X_{t_2t_2}+X_{t_1}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}X_{t_2}+t_1X=0, \quad X(0,0)=0,\quad X_{t_1}(0,0)+\frac{1}{\epsilon}X_{t_2}(0,0)=1.$$

Now let $X=X_0+\epsilon X_1+\ldots$, *(see note 1)* and then we get, at $O(\epsilon^{-1})$,
$$X_{0,t_2t_2}+X_{0,t_2}=0,\quad X_0(0,0)=X_{0,t_2}(0,0)=0,$$
at $O(1)$, 
$$X_{1,t_2t_2}+X_{1,t_2}=-2X_{0,t_1t_2}-X_{0,t_1}-t_1X_0,\quad X_1(0,0)=0,\quad X_{1,t_2}(0,0)+X_{0,t_1}(0,0)=1,$$
and at $O(\epsilon)$,
$$X_{2,t_2t_2}+X_{2,t_2}=-2X_{1,t_1t_2}-X_{1,t_1}-X_{0,t_1t_1}-t_1X_1,\quad X_2(0,0)=X_{2,t_2}(0,0)+X_{1,t_1}(0,0)=0.$$

Now, the solution of the $O(\epsilon^{-1})$ system is
$$X_0(t_1,t_2) = A_0(t_1)e^{-t_2}+B_0(t_1)$$ where $A_0(0)+B_0(0)=0$ and $-A_0(0)=0$, so $A_0(0)=B_0(0)=0$.

The $O(1)$ equations are now 
$$X_{1,t_2t_2}+X_{1,t_2}=-2\left(-A_0'(t_1)e^{-t_2}\right)-A_0'(t_1)e^{-t_2}-B_0'(t_1)-t_1A_0(t_1)e^{-t_2}-t_1B_0(t_1),\quad X_1(0,0)=0,\quad X_{1,t_2}(0,0)+X_{0,t_1}(0,0)=1,$$
which simplifies to $X_{1,t_2t_2}+X_{1,t_2}=e^{-t_2}\left(A_0'(t_1)-t_1A_0(t_1)\right)-B_0'(t_1)-t_1B_0(t_1)$. To avoid secular terms we require $A_0'(t_1)-t_1A_0(t_1)=0$ and $B_0'(t_1)+t_1B_1(t_1)=0$ *(see note 2)*. With the initial conditions we have, $A_0(0)=B_0(0)=0$, both $A_0$ and $B_0$ are $0$.

Now the $O(1)$ equations are nearly the same as the $O(\epsilon^{-1})$ equations:
$$X_{1,t_2t_2}+X_{1,t_2}=0,\quad X_1(0,0)=0,\quad X_{1,t_2}(0,0)=1,$$
except for the initial condition. The solution of this system is 
$$X_1(t_1,t_2) = A_1(t_1)e^{-t_2}+B_1(t_1)$$ where $A_1(0)+B_1(0)=0$ and $-A_1(0)=1$. So $A_1(0)=-1$ and $B_1(0)=1$. 
The $O(\epsilon)$ equation is then
$$X_{2,t_2t_2}+X_{2,t_2}=A_1'(t_1)e^{-t_2}-B_1'(t_1)-t_1A_1(t_1)e^{-t_2}-t_1B_1(t_1),\quad X_2(0,0)=0,\quad X_{2,t_2}(0,0)+A_1'(0)+B_1'(0)=0.$$
Again, to avoid secular terms we need $A_1'(t_1)-t_1A_1(t_1)=0$ and $B_1'(t_1)+t_1B_1(t_1)=0$. So $A_1(t_1)=ce^{t_1^2/2}$ and $B_1(t_1)=de^{-t_1^2/2}$, and the initial conditions give $c=-1$ and $d=1$.

We now have a full expression for $X_1$, so
$$ X_1(t_1,t_2)\approx-e^{t_1^2/2}e^{-t_2}+e^{-t_1^2/2},$$
or, in terms of $x$ and $t$, 
$$ x(t)=\epsilon \left(e^{-t^2/2}-e^{t^2/2}e^{-t/\epsilon}\right)+O(\epsilon^2). $$

This is very similar to the matched asymptotics result above, but it can be continued to get higher-order approximations. For example,
$$x(t)=\epsilon \left(e^{-t^2/2}-e^{t^2/2}e^{-t/\epsilon}\right)+\epsilon^2 e^{-t^2/2}\left(t-\frac{t^3}{3}\right)\left(1-e^{-t/\epsilon}\right)+O(\epsilon^3). $$

Note the growing term $e^{t^2/2-t/\epsilon}$ which grows with time. This is incorrect behaviour so the approximation is valid for early times.

[image]
Results with $\epsilon=0.2$. Shown are a numerical solution, the inner and outer solutions for the leading-order matched asymptotics and corresponding uniform approximation, and both of the multiple-scales results (ms1 and ms2). Note the very good agreement with the two-term multiple-scales expression and the numerical result.

---

*Note 1: We don't need to include $X_0$ since it will be zero, but I left it in for generality, and because I'm not sure if it's obvious that it will be zero.*

*Note 2: There's actually no real justification to remove terms that lead to things like $t_2e^{-t_2}$, but it is usually done, and it works.*

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but I think it might be useful nevertheless.

This equation can be solved exactly in terms of Airy functions. Let $x(t)=e^{\lambda t}W(t)$ and substitute into the differential equation to give (after factoring out $e^{\lambda t}$,
$$\epsilon\lambda^2 W(t)+2\epsilon\lambda W'(t)+\epsilon W''(t)+\lambda W(t)+W'(t)+tW(t)=0. $$
If $2\epsilon\lambda+1=0$ then we can remove the $W'$ terms, so $\lambda=-1/(2\epsilon)$ and $u=e^{-t/(2\epsilon)}$. This represents the slow decay in the solution for $x(t)$.

Now we are left with $$\frac{1}{4\epsilon} W+\epsilon W''-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}W+tW=0\Rightarrow \epsilon^2 W''+\left(\epsilon t-\frac{1}{4}\right)W=0.$$

The initial conditions are, in terms of $W$, $W(0)=0$ and $W'(0)=1$. Now let $$s=\frac{1-4\epsilon t}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}$$ and $H(s)=W(t)$ so that
$ H'(s)=-W'(t)\epsilon^{-1/3}$ and $H''(s)=\epsilon^{-2/3}W''(t)$. Then
$$H''(s)-sH(s)=0,\quad H\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)=0,\quad H'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)=-\epsilon^{1/3}.$$

This is the Airy differential equation, and its solution is a combination of Airy functions $\textrm{Ai}(s)$ and $\textrm{Bi}(s)$,
$$ H(s) =  c_1\textrm{Ai}(s)+c_2\textrm{Bi}(s),$$
and $c_1$ and $c_2$ satisfy
$$ c_1\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)+c_2\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)=0,\quad c_1\textrm{Ai}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)+c_2\textrm{Ai}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)=-\epsilon^{1/3}, $$
or 
$$c_1 = \epsilon^{1/3}\frac{-\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)}{\left(\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Bi}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)-\textrm{Ai}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\right)},$$ and 
$$c_2 = -\frac{\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)}{\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)} $$
Calculating these values of the Airy functions and their derivatives is not necessarily simple.

Substituting back for $W$ gives
$$ W(t) = c_1\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1-4\epsilon t}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)+c_2\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1-4\epsilon t}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right) $$
and so
$$x(t) = \frac{\epsilon^{1/3}e^{-t/(2\epsilon)}\left[-\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1-4\epsilon t}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)+\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1-4\epsilon t}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\right]}{\textrm{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Bi}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)-\textrm{Ai}'\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)\textrm{Bi}\left(\frac{1}{4\epsilon^{4/3}}\right)}. $$

I do think WKB theory is necessary for the asymptotics (especially if you replace $t$ by $\cos(t)$), and for the equation in terms of $W$ there will be three regions, one where $1/4-\epsilon t>0$, one where it is negative, and a connection region where it is small. The book "Introduction to perturbation methods" by Mark Holmes has a good section on WKB problems with turning points.

Comment: Thank you @David, this was very useful, I will check out the book you have recommended.